# Route to grouped routes with prefix correctly in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I have a group of routes with a prefix.

In my web routes the routes with an admin prefix go to a separate route file:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.', 'middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
    includeRouteFiles(__DIR__ . '/Admin/');
});
```

So I have to add `admin` as prefix in my routes. In my `Admin` directory I defined the routes as following:

```
Route::prefix('organization/{organization}')->group(function () {
    Route::post('seed', 'SeedController@store')->name('seed');
});
```

My problem is routing to the routes inside this group. I used the command `php artisan route:list` to see more info about my routes. It says:

- My route name is: `admin.seed`
- My URI is: `admin/organization/{organization}/seed`

When I link to this route as `admin.seed` in my form I get the following error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: admin.seed] [URI:
>   admin/organization/{organization}/seed]. (View:
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\minute-mn-503\resources\views\admin\organizations\show.blade.php)

I tried linking it as:

- `admin.seed`
- `admin/seed/1`
- `admin/organization/1/seed`
- `admin/organization/1.seed`

But none of them seems to work. This is the line of code for example:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin/organization/'.$organization->id.'.seed') }}">
```

Any idea on how I might route these correctly? I couldn't find any clear explanation in the Laravel docs.

Comment: Try this <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.seed',['organization'=>organization_id]) }}">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('admin/organization/' . $organization->id .'/seed') }}">
```

or:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.seed', $organization->id) }}">
```